# Need help in memory diagram

Tags: c++, casting

I am learning C++.

I want to have a nice view of the memory like whats going under the hood when the following codes of line run.

```
   // dynamic_cast
  #include <iostream>
  #include <exception>
  using namespace std;

  class CBase { virtual void dummy() {} };
  class CDerived: public CBase { int a; };

  int main () {
    try {
     CBase * pba = new CDerived;
     CBase * pbb = new CBase;
     CDerived * pd;

     pd = dynamic_cast<CDerived*>(pba);
     if (pd==0) cout << "Null pointer on first type-cast" << endl;

     pd = dynamic_cast<CDerived*>(pbb);
     if (pd==0) cout << "Null pointer on second type-cast" << endl;

     } catch (exception& e) {cout << "Exception: " << e.what();}
     system("PAUSE");
     return 0;
     }
```

Can anybody please help me..?

Comment: Which part(s) are you unsure of?

Comment: I'm not sure what such a diagram would look like.  Can you provide an example?

Comment: well if u can draw the first 4 lines ..It's okay with me

Comment: @cdhowie :somethign like this http://computer.howstuffworks.com/c29.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `pd = dynamic_cast<CDerived*>(pba);`, the situation looks like this:

```
pba ---> [CDerived]
          ^
pd -------'

pbb ---> [CBase]
```

I.e., `pba` and `pd` point to the same object. They are differently typed, however.

After `pd = dynamic_cast<CDerived*>(pbb);`, `pd` will be `0` (null) because the cast is invalid:

```
pba ---> [CDerived]

pd ----> (null)

pbb ---> [CBase]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what your actually question is but I'm assuming it is about how dynamic_cast<>() works. From a practical point of view it shouldn't matter how it is internally implemented, especially as it is implemented differently for different systems. There is book by Stanley Lippman ("Inside the C++ Object Model") which is a bit dated by now but still describes these details reasonably well to form a mental image. The important thing to note is that using dynamic_cast<>() isn't just viewing the object with a different type and possibly some minor adjustment but may involve a search in an internal representation of something akin to the inheritance tree.

That said, dynamic_cast(pba) roughly works like this:

1. Obtain a pointer to the internal type information (typically referred to as "virtual function pointer table" or "vtbl" although contemporary implementations don't use a vanilla virtual function pointer table) which identifies the type. For this to work the static type of the argument of the dyanmic_cast, in this case "CBase", needs to have at least one virtual function.
2. The type information in this object may coincide with the target type (as is e.g. the case in your example) in which case the system makes any necessary adjustments to the pointer (which are needed in in some cases involving multiple inheritance) and returns the corresponding pointer.
3. Otherwise, i.e. if the target type may be a base class of the dynamic type of the object, the system goes tries to find the target type in the base classes of the dynamic type. In the case of single inheritance this is reasonably simple but it can involve quite a bit of searching if multiple inheritance is involved.

That is, using dynamic_cast<>() frequently creates the potential to introduce a performance problem into your program. However, not using it where it is necessary create the potential of crashing your program. In general, the need for using dynamic_cast<>() is relatively rare. If you find yourself using dynamic_cast<>() a lot your design is almost certainly flawed.